capturing shell output from cucumber test in a readable form
I am attempting to write a cucuber test to run a shell command, and I cannot seem to get the output to show correctly...
I am trying to get a an apk file with appium and I want to make sure I can start the backend services before the testing starts....  When I run an exec command to start the servers I get a feakish output....
output
Í‘Ì¢Ì·Ì¢Í¢Ì•ÌªÌ°Í”Í”Ì»Ì»Í–Ì²Ì¬Ì–Ì¬Ì¯Ì™Í”Ì™Ì©Í•Ì»ÍˆÍ•Ì™ÍŽÌ±ÌŸÍ“Ì�Ì±ÍŽÌ¹Ì­ÍšÍ�ÌžÌ­ÍˆÌ¤Ì¼Í“ÌŸÌ¯Í‰Ì©ÍˆÌ—Ì¤ÍšÌžÌºÌ–Ì—Ì¦Ì°Ì¼Ì¤Ì™Í™Í�Ì© Ì‡ÍŠÌ‚Í£Í¦Ì‘Ì’Í¥Ì½Ì�ÌšÌŒÌ„Ì“Ì¨Ì�Ì�ÌœÍ™Í™Ì¹Ì«Í…Ì£Ì—Í•Í•Ì²Í”Í“Í…ÌŸÌ±ÍŽÌ®Ì£Ì­ÍŽÌ«ÌºÌ˜Ì—ÍˆÌ¹Ì™ÌžÍ–Ì™Ì¯Í‰Ì–Ì£Ì ÌªÍ•Ì¬Ì¬Ì©Ì�ÍˆÌ¦Ì©ÌžÌ£Í–Ì¼Ì™Í–Í�Ì–Ì¼Í™Í”Ì³ÍšÌ¬Í�Ì¤Ì³Ì˜Ì˜ÌªÌºtÌ‚Ì�Í¤Ì“Ì�ÍªÍ›ÍŒÌ½ÍŒÍ­Ì¶Í¡Ì¸Í Ì�Ì¼ÌªÌ¥Ì Í–Ì¬ÌžÌ¹Ì¦ÍŽÌ˜Ì¦ÍšÍ…Ì¤ÌªeÌ¾ÍŒÌŒÍ¨Í—Ì€Ì’Ì¾Í­Í­ÌŽÌ€Ì‹ Ò‰ÍœÍ¢Ì¡Ì¢Ì—Ì­Í™Í–Ì™Ì—Ì¯Ì©Ì¹Í™Ì­Ì—Í�Ì¼Ì¥Í™Ì¬Í�ÌªÌ¼Ì²Í�Í‡ÌœÍ�Ì±Í‰ÌªÌ�Ì—Í‡Ì¦Ì³Í‡Ì˜Í”sÍ‘Ì�ÌˆÍ©Ì¿Ì�Ì’Ì‡Í¤Ì�ÍœÍ Ì›Ì°ÌœÌ Ì˜ÌžÌ�ÌžÍ…Ì«ÍŽÌ®Ì«Ì©ÌºÌ¹Ì Í“Ì»Ì±Ì³Í–Ì³Ì©Ì—Ì¥ÍšÍ…Ì¤Ì¤tÌ¾Ì¿ÌŽÍ£Í‹ÍŠÌ…Ì�Ì‹Ì½Í†Ì€Í�Ì¼Ì²Ì»Ì³Ì¯ÍˆÍ”Í•Ì²ÌŸÌ¥Ì¥ÌžÌ¤Ì²iÌ�Ì‘ÌˆÍ©Í©Í†Ì¶ Ò‰Í•Ì�Ì¯Ì©ÌœÌ«ÌžÍ“Ì®Ì«Ì¬ÍŽÍ�ÌŸÌ™Ì®ÍšÍ”Ì³Ì™Í“Ì ÌºÍŽÌ˜ÍšÌ˜ÌŸÌ±Í•Í…Í‡Í‰Ì°nÌŽÌŒÌˆÍŒÌ¿Ì‡Í‹Í‹Ì“Í†ÌŠÌˆÍ�ÌµÌ®Ì°Í–Í‰ÌŸÍ–Í•Ì³Ì«Ì—Ì²ÍŽÌ³Ì™Í•Í•Ì²gÍ¤ÌŽÍ‹Ì‹Ì€ÍžÍžÍ“Í…Ì¯Í”Ì«ÌºÌ®ÍˆÌŸÌ©Ì³Ì­ÌœÍšÍ”Ì�Ì©Ì¦Ì±ÍˆÍˆÍŽÍšÌ¦ÌªÌ—ÍˆÌ—Í–Ì«Í…Ì�Ì²Í�Ì²Ì°Í–ÌŸÍšÍ…Ì¦ÌŸÌ¬Í“ÌŸÌ¯Ì¹Ì£Ìœ Í‹Ì‰Í¨Ì�Ì‹Ì’Í¨Ì½Í�Ì€Í Í˜Ì—ÌªÍ…Í–Ì¼ÍŽÍŽÌªÌ±Ì¥Í…Ì¤Ì©Í–Ì�Ì©Ì²Ì¹ÌºÌ£Ì«Ì»ÌœÌ¯Ì°Ì¯Ì»Ì¯ÌžÌžÍ™Ì«tÌ�ÍªÌ„Í‚ÌˆÌ�Í—Ì¿ÍžÌ´Í¢ Ò‰Í�Ì¹Ì±Ì±Í…ÌžÍˆÌ­Ì£Ì¯Ì¦ÌœÌ–Í‰ÍˆÍ…Ì¦Ì¬eÌ�Ì‘ÌˆÌ“Ì€Ì‰Ì„Í¨Ì�Ì�Í‹Í«Í¦Í‹ÌˆÌˆÌ¸Ì¶Ì•Ì¯Í™Ì¥Ì»Í“Í�Ì°Ì–Í“Í•Í‰Ì±Ì–Ì³Í‰Ì¯Í•ÌœÌ¼Ì®ÍŽÌ¯Ì®Ì¯Ì¤Ì»sÍŒÍ‹ÍŒÌ‘Ì†Í«ÍŠÍ’Í›Í†ÍŠÌ¾Í†Í¥ÍœÌ€Ì»Ì—ÌºÌ²Ì—ÌªÌ¬Ì™Í‰Í–ÌºÌŸÌ¦Í‡Ì˜ÍŽÍ“ÍŽÌ¬Ì£Í…Í™ÌœtÌ�Í§Ì‡ÌŠÍ�Í�Í¥ÌƒÍ�Í‹ÍžÌ•Ì¶Í�Í¡Ì˜Ì¤Ì™ÍŽÍ™Í�Ì¥Í–ÌžÌ±Í‡ÍˆÍ•Ì³Í‰Í‡Í�Ì®Í�Ì�Ì°Ì±Ì­Í”Ì®Ì­ÌœÌ¦Ì­Í“Ì¥Ì³Ì–Í“Ì¦ÍˆÌ°Í‰Í”Ì–Ì£Ì£Í–Ì¯Ì£Ì¥ÍŽÌ£Ì¥ÍŽiÍ¯Ì„Í¦Í›Ì€Ì�Í—Ì�Í Í�Ì£Ì¥Ì±Ì±ÌªÍ�Í”Ì–Ì¼ÌªnÍŠÍ¨Ì�Ì¿ÌŒÌ¡Í ÌµÍŸÌ·ÍˆÌ®Í…ÌœÌ»Ì¦Ì¤Ì©ÌžÌ¹Ì Ì©Ì¦Ì±Ì±Ì²ÍˆÌ²Í™Ì�Ì£Ì¥Í‰Ì¤Ì�Ì¯Ì�Í�Ì®ÌªÌ¤Í…Ì¹Í“ÌŸÌªÌ˜ÌŸÌŸÍ…Ì Í–Ì¼Í…Ì¬Ì–ÌœÌŸÍ�Í–

rather than a nice readable output....
any ideas why I cannot get a proper output ?
package.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "wdio run wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "8.39.0",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^8.1.3",
    "@wdio/browserstack-service": "^8.1.3",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.1.3",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "8.1.2",
    "@wdio/globals": "^8.1.3",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^8.1.2",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.1.3",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^8.1.3",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^8.1.2",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.1.2",
    "@wdio/sync": "7.27.0",
    "allure-commandline": "2.29.0",
    "appium": "^2.4.0",
    "appium-chromedriver": "5.6.41",
    "appium-uiautomator2-driver": "^2.29.10",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cucumber": "6.0.7",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^1.5.0",
    "cucumber-tsflow": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "fs-extra": "11.2.0",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "3.6.1",
    "request": "^2.34",
    "run": "1.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.0.1",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "5.1.8",
    "wdio-wait-for": "^3.0.1",
    "webdriverio": "8.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/codemod": "^0.12.0",
    "axios": "1.6.7",
    "force": "0.0.3",
    "jscodeshift": "^0.14.0",
    "request-promise-native": "1.0.9"
  }
}

and i have the config like so..
wdio.conf.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exports.config = {
    exclude: [],
    logLevel: 'info',
    bail: 0,
    waitforTimeout: 20000,
    services: ['appium'],
    path: '/wd/hub/',
    runner: 'local',
    capabilities: [
        {
            platformName: 'Android',
            port: 4723,
            'appium:sessionOverride': false,
            'appium:debugLogSpacing': true,
            'appium:connectionRetryTimeout': 30000,
            'appium:maxInstances': 1,
            'appium:maxInstancesPerCapability': 1,
            'appium:connectionRetryCount': 5,
            'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
            'appium:nativeInstrumentsLib': true,
            'appium:isolateSimDevice': true,
            'appium:noReset': false,
            'appium:relaxedSecurity': true,
            "appium:autoGrantPermissions": true,
            "appium:autoLaunch": true,
            'appium:ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError': true,
        },
    ],

    framework: 'cucumber',
    specs: [
        './tests/features/*.feature',
    ],
    maxInstances: 1,

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['./tests/features/step-definitions/*.js'],
        timeout: 100000,
        reportFilePerRetry: false
    },
};


and some a simple exec test ...
feature
Feature: Launch Application

  Scenario: Launching a application
    Given a application
    When I launch the application
    Then the application should run successfully


and a step file like
const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

Given('a application', function () {
    console.log('application is ready to be launched.');
});

When('I launch the application', function (callback) {
    exec('bash -c "ping remoteHost"', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return callback(error);
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        callback();
    });
});

Then('the application should run successfully', function () {
    console.log('Application ran successfully.');
});


so to kick it off it is a simple install and run the tests
npm install
npm run test

nodejs installes everything, appium starts up but when the exec test starts the garbled output nevert stops and I am expecting a simple ping output like so...
ping localhost

Pinging remoteHost [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-se

Does anyone know why this is happening to poor little me ?
Thanks in advance for pointing out the errors in my ways...
ta,
X

So, It appears I over engineered the crap out of this, and the wdio and cucumber tests are not required to run the cmd step.  I just reorganized the execution...

NPM install
run the init command in bash
run the tests...

Running the init commands in the test script is a bad idea and it actually runs through the wido driver. Hence the garbled output.
